# How can I pass props to layouts used in react-router?

Tags: reactjs

Assume the following Route setup:

```
ReactDOM.render(  
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/">
                <Route component={Layout} onEnter={checkIndexAuthorization(store)}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                </Route>

                <Route component={AuthLayout} onEnter={checkLoginAuthorization(store)}>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

As you can see, there are two main layouts, the normal `Layout` and the login page `AuthLayout`. The normal layout is used for the app proper.

Below, you can see the `Layout` component file:

```
//========================================
// IMPORTS
//========================================

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

//========================================
// COMPONENT
//========================================

const Layout = props => (
    <main className="app">
        <header>
            {props.sectionTitle}
        </header>

        <section>
            {props.children}
        </section>

        <footer>

        </footer>
    </main>
)

Layout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    sectionTitle: PropTypes.string // <-- not being set anywhere currently
}

//========================================
// EXPORTS
//========================================

export default Layout;
```

Now, that layout has a title section at the top, that needs to display text based on where in the app we are.

As I'm new to React JS, I didn't want to just look up 'how to pass props from router' or similar - rather, I'm interested in what the *correct* way to do this might be. The 'React way', if you will. Whether that involves passing props directly from the route, or changing a global state of some kind to affect the title, or whatever the 'correct' way of handling this scenario would be.

EDIT: I should mention that I'm using React JS v. 15.6.1, and react-router v. 3.0.5.

Comment: Take my experience with a large grain of salt, but in general, I think you want to avoid passing your props via your routes. You want to try and only pass them via your components. If you have a deep project structure, that can obviously get very tedious, and that's when you would look into something like Redux to manage your global state. It makes passing the pieces of the state that you only care about to the proper components. 

If you're still interested in passing props via routes, this github thread is helpful: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4627

Comment: So how might I do that? I guess what I'm having trouble conceptualizing is, the routes are the only thing that's actually _changing_, so how does one display the correct title based on the route, if one doesn't use the route to determine it?

Comment: Again, if you're passing a title via your actual route within params, then that's a good way to pass something. Consider a route that it something like `/myroute/:title`. The `:title` syntax is saying "give me anything here, and I'll call it a title". And let's say within another component you say ````<Link to=`/myroute/${dynamicTitle}` />```` - you can then access the `title` within this route's component via `this.props.match.params.title`

Comment: Unfortunately the titles are not nearly so well-defined as far the routes go. For example, the route `/home` has a section title of `Playbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you are trying to achieve is to get the name of the Component / Page you are in dynamically.
If this is the case, you can add a prop called `name` to the route and grab it inside the component.
For example:

```
 <Route path="/" name="App" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute name="Home Page" component={HomePage} />
  <Route path="/home" name="Home Page" component={HomePage} />
  <Route path="/about" name="About Page" component={AboutPage} />
  <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
</Route>
```

and inside the component this is how to grab the name:

```
render() {
// ...
    const currentRouteName = this.props.routes[this.props.routes.length - 1].name;
// ... rest of code
```

Comment: This _is_ what I'm trying to achieve, and this does seem the least over-engineered solution, but I do want to make sure that whatever solution I implement will follow proper practices as far as React JS is concerned - and this doesn't seem particularly scaleable to me. As the application grows more and more routes and potentially we need to start passing more variables than just the section title.

Comment: Well we use it in production on a mid scale application and it's doing fine.  as for passing props to routes, well a route is just a component, if it needs certain props then you need to provide them. like you would do with any other component.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at this too - in my application I have private routes which are only available after Authentication, which I only remembered after about 5 minutes of looking at this!

If you are creating private routes in your application, do not forget to pass props to the newly created route component e.g.:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/path/to/route" name={'Route name'} component={RouteComponent} layout={SimpleLayout} />
```

And the definition for PrivateRoute:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ layout: Layout, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        const newComponent = Layout ? 
             <Layout><Component {...rest} {...props} /></Layout> 
                 : 
             <Component {...props} />;

        return Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
            newComponent
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location }}} />
        )
    }}/>
);
```

The important part is remembering to spread to current props onto the new Component {...rest}.

Then in the actual Layout file (eg. SimpleLayout above) you can access the props via:

```
this.props.children.props.name
```

I'm sure there are still better ways of doing this, but from my experience thus far, this worked ok for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your all child component to have additional property "title". For ex update Home component as below

```
Home.title = "HomePage";

export default Home
```

Now update your routes to pass this info as a prop

```
<Route component={Layout} onEnter={checkIndexAuthorization(store)}>
     <IndexRoute component={Home} />
     <Route path="/home" component={Home} title={Home.title} />
</Route>
```

Now in Layout component you can access this from children props like below

```
<header>
    {props.children.route.component.title}
</header>
```